# Google Analytics API tutorial issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics

I am following the tutorial to create automated reporting for Google Analytics: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/reporting-apps-script

When I construct the script via the instructions there and click "play", I get this error back on the original spreadsheet.

`"outputToSpreadsheet" is not defined.`

It's my first time using Apps Script.  I understand what the error is saying, but I'm confused because I followed the instructional code exactly.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: The error means that there is no function of ``outputToSpreadsheet`` in the script. So can you provide your latest script? It will help users think of the solution of your issue.